# How to hide div element with class name in webpage in android?

Tags: android

The below code works perfectly for hiding the element with id but how do I hide element with class? This is not working, I have used `document.getElementsByClassName('logo').style.display='none'` as javascript code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            WebView webView;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {document.getElementById('header').style.display='none';})()");
                    }
                });
                webView.loadUrl(url);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> document.getElementById returns Single Element where as
>   document.getElementsByClass returns arrays of objects

that's why it's not working
try the below code

```
var a =  document.getElementsByClassName("logo");
    for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
    a[index].style.display='none';
   }
```